# SQLite: Retrieve whats just been added?

Tags: sqlite, auto-increment

I have an autoincrementing ID field. What I would like to do is retrieve the value that gets assigned to this ID field after I've done an INSERT command.

Can somebody please tell me how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `last_insert_rowid()`:

```
SELECT last_insert_rowid();
```

Comment: Cool! I'll accept your answer when I'm able to. This works great for me: SELECT * from Table where ID=last_insert_rowid()